# What is wrong with this logfile., Can anybody please point me to the right direction?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I made a picture of log, can anybody please tell me whats wrong with the ng e2e?[image]

I am really sorry for the format of package.json file.

///package.json file`
{
  "name": "planning",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.7.0",
    "jasmin": "0.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "tassign": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}

`

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: also, can you share the package.json file?

Comment: Do you use e2e? If not, I recommend that you create a new project, copy the files of the e2e folder and put at this project, the error is inside node_modules, could be something installed wrong there

Comment: I do use e2e. I also thought about that. Must try it out. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downgraded my Nodejs version from latest to the one from last years summer, I think it was and it helped.